# While loop: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

I've been reading about Pandas and trying to write some simple snippets. I've seen many people asking about the `ValueError` raised by Pandas but can't figure out how to accomplish the following: I have a simple dataframe:

```
Driver_Name Month/Year  Km_driven   Salaray
0   Ivaylo_Ivanov   Jan/21  2168    3208.64
1   Ivaylo_Ivanov   Feb/21  2350    3478.00
2   Ivaylo_Ivanov   Mar/21  3126    4626.48
3   Ivaylo_Ivanov   Apr/21  2415    3574.20
4   Ivaylo_Ivanov   May/21  2115    3130.20
5   Mihail Styanov  Jan/21  2678    3963.44
6   Mihail Styanov  Feb/21  3185    4713.80
7   Mihail Styanov  Mar/21  3280    4854.40
8   Mihail Styanov  Apr/21  3012    4457.76
9   Mihail Styanov  May/21  2980    4410.40
10  Petar_Petkov    Jan/21  2013    2979.24
11  Petar_Petkov    Feb/21  2089    3091.72
12  Petar_Petkov    Mar/21  2163    3201.24
13  Petar_Petkov    Apr/21  2098    3105.04
14  Petar_Petkov    May/21  2179    3224.92
15  Ivan_Ivanov Jan/21  2876    4256.48
16  Ivan_Ivanov Feb/21  2900    4292.00
17  Ivan_Ivanov Mar/21  2987    4420.76
18  Ivan_Ivanov Apr/21  3016    4463.68
19  Ivan_Ivanov May/21  2019    2988.12
```

I would like to have a while loop as follows:

```
while df['Driver_Name']=='Ivaylo_Ivanov':
        do something
```

I know that `df['Driver_Name']=='Ivaylo_Ivanov'` returns a boolean series, but why can't the `while` statement iterate over the boolean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: "why can't the while statement iterate over the boolean" - that's not how a while statement works. the while loop evaluates the condition on each loop as either `True` or `False`, and continues running until it the condition *evaluates to* `False`.  It's not iterating through an array. so this is equivalen to `if array` or `assert array` - it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following if you like to iterate through all rows:

```
for index, row in df.loc[df['Driver_Name'] == 'Ivaylo_Ivanov'].iterrows():
       do something
```

You are locating every row, where the condition is true and itarate through the rows.

You should'n use loops, if you have a large dataframe, thera are a many other ways.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The `while` keyword expects a `bool` expression, *not* an array (series) of them. If you want to iterate over such series until you find a `False`, you could easily accomplish that with a simple `for` loop, or, as the Backtrace message suggests, using the member functions `all`, `any`, etc.